# Android Non-Constant Expressions: Migration Necessary

Tags: android, eclipse, api

I have been told I must change my switch statements to If-Else statements due to changes in API 14.

Thats fine.

What isn't working is when I place my caret over the switch statement and press CTRL-1 as per the instructions I am given no options, I am using Ubuntu by the way, any suggestions?

I've also tried cleaning my project.

edit. Its working for all other switch statements just not the one contained here:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.btnCalcCalories:
            double weight = Integer.parseInt(etWeight.getText().toString());
            double bodyfat = Integer.parseInt(etBodyfat.getText().toString());
            ;
            lbm = weight * (100 - bodyfat) / 100;
            bmr = 370 + (21.6 * lbm);
            maintCals = bmr * actLevel;

            maintCalories
                    .setText("Calories need to maintain current bodyweight: "
                            + String.valueOf(maintCals));

            lbmResult.setText("Your Lean Body Mass is " + String.valueOf(lbm)
                    + "Kg");
            bmrResult.setText("Your Base Metabolic rate is "
                    + String.valueOf(bmr) + " calories");
            calorieResult.setText("Your Daily calorie goal is "
                    + String.valueOf(finalGPercentage) + " calories");
            break;
        case R.id.btnUpdateDB:
            boolean worked = true;
            try {
                String dbWeight = curWeight.getText().toString();
                String dbWaist = curWaist.getText().toString();
                String dbChest = curChest.getText().toString();
                String dbLegs = curLegs.getText().toString();
                String dbArms = curArms.getText().toString();

                Stats entry = new Stats(MainActivity.this);
                entry.open();
                entry.createEntry(dbWeight, dbWaist, dbChest, dbArms, dbLegs);
                entry.close();
                break;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                worked = false;
                String error = e.toString();
                Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                d.setTitle("Error");
                TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                tv.setText(error);
                d.setContentView(tv);
                d.show();
            } finally {
                if (worked) {
                    Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                    d.setTitle("DB Worked");
                    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                    tv.setText("Success");
                    d.setContentView(tv);
                    d.show();
                }
            }

        case R.id.btnViewDB:
            Intent i = new Intent("com.uhi.fatfighter.DBView");
            startActivity(i);
            break;
        case R.id.btnStopwatchActivity:
            Intent s = new Intent("com.uhi.fatfighter.Stopwatch");
            startActivity(s);
            break;
        case R.id.btnMapARun:
            Intent m = new Intent("com.uhi.fatfighter.MapRun");
            startActivity(m);
            break;
        case R.id.btnWeightConverter:
            Intent w = new Intent("com.uhi.fatfighter.WeightConverter");
            startActivity(w);
            break;
        }

    }
```

Comment: I don't know why you feel the need to change, but if you aren't getting eclipse to do it automatically can you really not figure out how to do it by hand?  I guarantee its quicker than waiting for an answer here.

Comment: its not that i feel the need, I'm trying to get google maps to work with my app and since i added it as a reference eclipse is now demanding this of me.. plus there are quite a few switch / cases to work through, been at my comp for near 12 hours now, clicking and pointing would be nice before bed :)

Comment: For readability, you normally don't pile all the onclicks into 1 function like that-  make separate onClickListener objects with their own functions for each button, and you can get rid of the switches and have more readable names (like WeightConverterListener, ViewDbListener, etc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my project properties I had my Google-libs checked as 'is library', unchecked this and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. The problem is that Eclipse is stupid. You should use IntelliJ IDEA if you want do cool stuff like this.
2. Don't forget to call **trim()** method to remove trailing spaces.

   *double weight = Integer.parseInt(etWeight.getText().toString());*
3. Using **magic numbers** is not good manner.

   *bmr = 370 + (21.6 x lbm);*
4. Catching root **Exception** is not good manner.

   *catch (Exception e)*
5. Never show Dialog in finally block, your application may crash at this time.